# PHP не работает. Не знаю, что делать.

Tags: php

Народ... Расскажите, как сохранять страницу PHP на компе, что такое локальный сервер, что такое Денвер и зачем он нужен. Содержание страницы правильное. В вопросе послать не могу - не видит. Но всё же постараюсь.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN "http:w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title> shporgalka_PHP </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$d='Вывод переменной $d произведён';
echo $d;
$a = 4;
$b = 5;
$c = $a +$b;
echo $c;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Ты же вроде уже спрашивал это же самое. Тебе не ответили?

Answer (score 1):

Да тут с нуля надо просто изучать все самому, никто тут не будет, я думаю, объяснять курс лекций по php и серверам.

А денвер - это по сути и есть локальный сервер на твоем компе. Установка его, вряд ли может вызвать какие-либо трудности. Запустить - тем более. Там ярлыки на рабочем столе сохранятся.

Далее кидай свой файл в c:\webserver(<<<смотря в какую папку установил>>>)\home\localhost\www к примеру и в браузере переходи по адресу

http://localhost/имяфайла.php

По идее все должно работать )